# Write a Java program to evaluate an expression in postfix notation - Data Structures and Algorithms class

Tags: java, data-structures

This is a Data Structures and Algorithms class assignment. I don't want the answer, I just need some help on where to even begin. The teacher recites from the book, which is some help, but not much. There is base code below with a space that I am meant to fill in. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Stacks are used by compilers to evaluate expressions and generate machine-language code. Humans generally write expressions like 3 + 4 and 7 / 9, in which the operator (+ or / here) is written between its operands. This is called inﬁx notation. To evaluate a complex inﬁx expression, a compiler would ﬁrst convert the expression to postﬁx notation, in which the operator is written to the right of its two operands. The preceding inﬁx expressions would appear in postﬁx notation as 3 4 + and 7 9 /, respectively. You are required to write a Java program to evaluate an expression in postﬁx notation and display the result. Assume that an expression ONLY contains parentheses, single-digit integers (as operands) and the following operators: “+”, “-”, “*”, “/”, “%”. The expressions in inﬁx notation are given in the ﬁle InﬁxExpressions.txt. The corresponding expressions in postﬁx notation are given in the ﬁle PostﬁxExpressions.txt. Your program should read the expressions from the ﬁle PostﬁxExpressions.txt, evaluate each postﬁx expression, and display the result in a tabular report. The partial Java program is given in the ﬁle PostﬁxEvaluator.java. Fill in the missing code in PostﬁxEvaluator.java to make the program complete and work properly. The test driver is given in the ﬁle TestDriver.java. You are required to create a package named labs.lab3 to include all the classes. The sample output of the program is given in the ﬁle SampleOutput.txt.

Infix expressions:

```
1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5
1 * 2 * 3 / 2 / 3
1 + 2 * 3 - 4 / 2
1 * 2 + 3 - 4 / 5
1 + 2 * 4 % 3 + 4
( 1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 / 2
5 * ( 4 + 3 ) - 2 / 1
( ( 1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) / 2
( 5 + 4 % 3 - 2 ) / 2
1 + 2 * 4 / ( 2 + 2 )
```

Postfix expressions:

```
1 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 -
1 2 * 3 * 2 / 3 /
1 2 3 * + 4 2 / -
1 2 * 3 + 4 5 / -
1 2 4 * 3 % + 4 +
1 2 + 3 * 4 2 / -
5 4 3 + * 2 1 / -
1 2 + 3 * 4 - 2 /
5 4 3 % + 2 - 2 /
1 2 4 * 2 2 + / +
```

Sample Output:

```
Postfix Expression            Evaluation Result             
1 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 -             -1                            
1 2 * 3 * 2 / 3 /             1                             
1 2 3 * + 4 2 / -             5                             
1 2 * 3 + 4 5 / -             5                             
1 2 4 * 3 % + 4 +             7                             
1 2 + 3 * 4 2 / -             7                             
5 4 3 + * 2 1 / -             33                            
1 2 + 3 * 4 - 2 /             2                             
5 4 3 % + 2 - 2 /             2                             
1 2 4 * 2 2 + / +             3
```

Partial Code:

```
package labs.lab3;

import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class PostfixEvaluator
{
    private Stack<Integer> stack;
    private String expression;

    public PostfixEvaluator(String e)
    {
        stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        expression = e;
    }

        // Evaluate the postfix expression and return the evaluation result
    public int Evaluate()
    {
      /* Missing code start here */



          /* Missing code end here */
    }

    // Perform an operation on the two operands
    public int Calculate(int operand1, int operand2, char operation)
    {
        int result = 0;

        switch (operation)
        {
        case '+':
            result = operand1 + operand2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = operand1 - operand2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = operand1 / operand2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = operand1 * operand2;
            break;
        case '%':
            result = operand1 % operand2;
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm to evaluate a postfix expression is pretty simple. The idea is that you push operands onto the stack until you encounter an operator. Then you pop two operands off the stack, apply the operand, and push the result back onto the stack. When you're done, the final result is on the stack.

For example, given the postfix expression `4 5 + 3 *`:

1. Read '4'. It's an operand, so push it onto the stack. Stack contains `[4]`.
2. Read '5'. It's an operand, so push it onto the stack. Stack contains `[5,4]`.
3. Read '+'. It's an operator. Pop 5 and 4 from the stack. Stack contains `[]`.
4. Add 5 and 4, giving 9. Push it onto the stack. Stack contains `[9]`.
5. Read '3'. It's an operand, so push it onto the stack. Stack contains `[3,9]`.
6. Read '*'. It's an operator. Pop 3 and 9 from the stack. Stack contains `[]`.
7. Multiply 9 and 3, giving 27. Push it onto the stack. Stack contains `[27]`.
8. You've reached the end of input. Pop result from stack.

If at any time there aren't enough operands on the stack, then there's an error. If at the end of input, you have more than one value on the stack, then there's an error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would the syntax for this look like? I've been using powershell lately and my Java is real rusty.

Comment: @user10520145 And my Java is almost non-existent. If you want code, either write it yourself or do a search. A search for [java postfix evaluation] reveals lots of implementations. You said in your question that you don't want the answer, but rather a place to begin. I gave you the place to start.

Comment: For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450815/postfix-evaluation-using-stacks

Answer (score -1):

```
// Java program to evaluate value of a postfix
// expression having multiple digit operands
import java.util.Stack;
 
class Test1
{
    // Method to evaluate value of a postfix expression
    static int evaluatePostfix(String exp)
    {
        //create a stack
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
         
        // Scan all characters one by one
        for(int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = exp.charAt(i);
             
            if(c == ' ')
            continue;
             
            // If the scanned character is an operand
            // (number here),extract the number
            // Push it to the stack.
            else if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                int n = 0;
                 
                //extract the characters and store it in num
                while(Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    n = n*10 + (int)(c-'0');
                    i++;
                    c = exp.charAt(i);
                }
                
 
                //push the number in stack
                stack.push(n);L
            }
             
            // If the scanned character is an operator, pop two
            // elements from stack apply the operator
            else
            {
                int val1 = stack.pop();
                int val2 = stack.pop();
                 
                switch(c)
                {
                    case '+':
                    stack.push(val2+val1);
                    break;
                     
                    case '-':
                    stack.push(val2- val1);
                    break;
                     
                    case '/':
                    stack.push(val2/val1);
                    break;
                     
                    case '*':
                    stack.push(val2*val1);
                    break;
            }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
     
    // Driver program to test above functions
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String exp = "100 200 + 2 / 5 * 7 +";
        System.out.println(evaluatePostfix(exp));
    }
}
```

this is the code for the evaluate

Comment: From the questioner's question: "I don't want the answer, I just need some help on where to even begin"